# Facebook like button not rendering in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, facebook, browser, facebook-like, rendering

I really hope someone can get me started on this one.

I generated the HTML5 integration code for the Facebook like and share buttons using the facebook developer form. After integrating the code on a client's website, the buttons are only shown using Chrome, but they are not rendering in Firefox or IE.

Looking at the generated code it seems that the Facebook API does not create the code needed to show the buttons when using the latter.

I searched quite a lot and experimented with all kind of initializations (synchronous vs asynchronous loading, different integration methods like iFrames, xml declarations, app publishing, etc...) - with no change in behaviour at all.

I also thought I might have trouble with other scripts running on the page, but when creating a new website only holding the like button codes the problem remains.

By now I am running out of ideas and I cannot find anyone having the same problem. Seems to be some stupid error I cannot see myself. Would someone help me out having a look at:

- http://www.berliner-bueroverzeichnis.de
- http://www.berliner-bueroverzeichnis.de/debug.html

CODE:
    
    
    Insert title here

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '470372866398003', // App ID
status     : true, // check login status
cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/berlinbueros.de" data-width="250" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: But I can see it in all three browsers. O_o